# Gravity not set properlywith LayoutParams in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layoutparams

I have a chat `activity` that is arranging messages based on the username of the sender. All of the behavior outlined in `onBindViewHolder` is working properly, except for the Gravity of the container (all messages are aligning end when they should be aligning start and end for partner and logged in user, respectively). What have I done wrong in the implementation of `LayoutParams`?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DMViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // This method fills fields with data for each list item


    Message message = messageList.get(position);

    String signedInUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    boolean isSignedInUser = message.getAuthorUID().equals(signedInUserID);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

    holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
    holder.date.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(message.getTimestamp()));


    if (isSignedInUser) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END);
        holder.singleDMContainer.setLayoutParams(params);

        holder.textContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_message_text_background);
    } else {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START);
        holder.singleDMContainer.setLayoutParams(params2);

        holder.textContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.partner_message_text_background);
    }


}
```

and the xml file for the messages:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/singleDMContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/user_message_text_background">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dm_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_extralight"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/sample_message"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dm_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dm_message"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_extralight"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/sample_time"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the rule to the child view, not to the container: replace

```
holder.singleDMContainer.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

with

```
holder.textContainer.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

UPDATE:

Also use `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START` instead of `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START`, and `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END` instead of `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END`.

Comment: They still appear on the same side. Oddly enough, all messages align Start when I do it this way instead of End.

Comment: This did it. I was reading the wrong documentation. Thank you.